# How to distort an iconButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would need some help with the IconButton of Flutter...
I tried to use "SizedBox"(as a parent of the IconButton) and "icon size" to change the relation from height to width... Is there a possibility to distort the IconButoon?

Edit 15.05.21

Tried the fittedBox, but it doesn't change anything... Maybe I'm using it wrong!?

```
Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(                                           
                  child: Container(
                    width: 250,  //width of the button should be 250
                    height: 170,  //height of the button should be 170
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Image.asset('assets/Images/image.png'),
                          padding:EdgeInsets.all(0.0) ,
                          iconSize:170, //use iconSize or not doesn't make a difference
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherPage()),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: you can use fittedBox.

Comment: thank you @BenjaminLee ...I tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to give it a fit of BoxFit.fill. See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to distort any widget in Flutter (And yes, that's literally any widget. You could even distort an entire scaffold if you wanted to).

One is with Transform. Use if you care what the scaleX or scaleY is, but don't care to specify the exact height / width.

Another is FittedBox.

Transform can also do rotations and skewing. FittedBox is generally more convenient for layouts.

I've coded a main.dart that demonstrates these.

Here's the screen, with an altered icon on the left, an icon distorted by FittedBox in the center, and an icon distorted by transform on the right :

[image: the screen, with an altered icon on the left, an icon distorted by FittedBox in the center, and an icon distorted by transform on the right]

And here's the code (Note that in order for fitted box to distort its contents, you need to pass it the fit property of BoxFit.fill):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Icon(Icons.android, color: Colors.green),
          Container(
              width: 250, //width of the button should be 250
              height: 170, //height of the button should be 170
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                child: Icon(Icons.android, color: Colors.blue),
              )),
          Center(
            child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(7, 1, 1),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.android,
                  color: Colors.red,
                )),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```